# Karma Chai How to access DOM element

Tags: chai

I am writing test cases using Karma Mocha.

Following is my function:

```
fun : function()
{

  if(a == 1)
  $("#test").hide();

}
```

We set the DOM element property based on some condition.

While writing its test:

```
   it('fun', function (){       
     var a = 1; 
   // how do I test the DOM element.
   // Is it possible to access the DOM element of the source file in the test file.

    })
```

I tried using chai-jquery but it accesses only body and not the other elements.I guess it works on DOM elements of test file.
Can anyone please help.?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your jQuery loaded upon testing then you would select you element with `$('#test')` and then do you tests.

Like so:

```
describe('obj.fun', function (){
  before(function() {
    $('<div id="test"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
  });

  after(function() {
    $('#test').remove();
  });

  it('should hide the element when a is 1', function() {
    var $test = $('#test');
    expect( $test.is(':hidden') ).to.be.false;
    obj.a = 1;
    obj.fun();
    expect( $test.is(':hidden') ).to.be.true;
  });
});
```